# How to take distinct values by time in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document structure like this:

```
"_source" : {
      "symbol" : "GOOG",
      "bidPrice" : 309.09,
      "askPrice" : 309.11,
      "timeStamp" : "2019-12-03T05:54:54.0656988-08:00"
      },
```

...

```
 "_source" : {
      "symbol" : "FB",
      "bidPrice" : 309.09,
      "askPrice" : 309.11,
      "timeStamp" : "2019-12-03T05:54:54.0656988-08:00"
      },
```

There are several different symbols in that index, and multiple states for that the same symbol but with different timestamps. How can I select last created document for each symbol?

I have tried this:

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "timeStamp": "desc"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ticker" : {"terms" : { "field" : "symbol.keyword"}
    }
  }
}
```

But this returns only list of symbols, but not the last document for selected symbol. How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I have managed to solve this problem by my own:

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "timeStamp": "desc"
  },
  "collapse" : {
    "field" : "symbol.keyword" 
  }
}
```